# How to center and scale object threejs

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js

I am using the following code to scale and center a msgpack compressed object loaded using the ObjectLoader and it is not working. I think that my object has a rotation on it, and hence causing weird behaviors. On some objects, it successfully centers, but on others the centering is offset and scaling isn't right either.

In this snippet, result is the scene from the ObjectLoader. My thought was that the object was not very well formed, but I'm not sure. I wanted the table on the image or any other user entered mesh to be on the top of the grid, centered and scaled so that the maximum size is 1 unit.

Each square measures 0.25, the axis are at 0,0,0 https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkKYC.png

```
    // result is a threejs scene        
    var geometry = result.children[0].geometry;
    var mesh = result.children[0];
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    var middle = new THREE.Vector3();
    middle.x        = ( geometry.boundingBox.max.x + geometry.boundingBox.min.x ) / 2;
    middle.y        = -geometry.boundingBox.min.y;
    middle.z        = ( geometry.boundingBox.max.z + geometry.boundingBox.min.z ) / 2;
    middle.negate();
    mesh.position.copy(middle);
    // scales the mesh up to maxsize
    var maxSize = 1;
    // gets the biggest axis
    var maxVal = geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x;
    if (maxVal < geometry.boundingBox.max.y - geometry.boundingBox.min.y) {
        maxVal = geometry.boundingBox.max.y - geometry.boundingBox.min.y;
    }
    if (maxVal < geometry.boundingBox.max.z - geometry.boundingBox.min.z) {
        maxVal = geometry.boundingBox.max.z - geometry.boundingBox.min.z;
    // scales the current size proportional to the maxval, times maxsize
    mesh.scale.divideScalar(maxVal * maxSize);

    self.scene.add(result);
```

Comment: The bounding box is the red square around the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling `geometry.computeBoundingBox();` call `geometry.center();` then you don't need the `middle.x` or `middle.z` and you can just call `mesh.translateY()` rather than fiddling with `middle` at all

Comment: And how do I know the parameter for translateY since the object is uploaded by the user? I'd have to use the bounding box for that too, and use the middle.y ?

Comment: `.center()` will already set the bounding box for you, so it's just simple arithmetic at that point.